# How to connect Azure DB(MFA) using Azure OpenAI and get dynamic query result

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, azure-openai

Which Nuget package can be use to access Azure DB(with multi-factor authentication) from Azure OpenAI and get query result by specifying query as a sentence using C#?

Answer (score 0):

I think *Azure OpenAI client library for .NET* Nuget package can be used.

*The Azure OpenAI client library for .NET is an adaptation of OpenAI's REST APIs that provides an idiomatic interface and rich integration with the rest of the Azure SDK ecosystem. It can connect to Azure OpenAI resources or to the non-Azure OpenAI inference endpoint, making it a great choice for even non-Azure OpenAI development.*

Link to the Nuget package is below:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.AI.OpenAI/

**This is a prerelease version of Azure.AI.OpenAI.**